# Using push() to create a JSON object with the name being a variable?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm trying to create a JSON object which looks something like this:

```
{
    "scores": [{
        "879212387": {
            "elo": 125
        }, {
        "123768901": {
            "elo": 173
        }
    }]
}
```

(where the numbers under json.scores are a variable named sid64)

but instead I just get something which looks like this

```
{
    "scores": [{
        "sid64": {
            "elo": 125
        }, {
        "sid64": {
            "elo": 173
        }
    }]
}
```

How can I dictate that I'm trying to make the object name a variable and not a string?

Current code:

```
obj.scores.push({
    sid64:
        {
            elo
        }
    })
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a variable for a key in a JavaScript object literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/how-to-use-a-variable-for-a-key-in-a-javascript-object-literal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the computed property syntax:

```
obj.scores.push({
    [sid64]:
    {
        elo
    }
})
```

It indicates that you want to use the value of the expression inside `[...]` as the key, not the string `sid64`.

Comment: "The special syntax" has a name ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to use objects [computed property name](https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/javascript-object-creation-356e504173a8)

```
obj.scores.push({
    [sid64]://rest of the code
```